# pkexec doesn't show onscreen keyboard

Tags: debian, pkexec

I have an web application that runs on a pc without a physical keyboard that is opened in chrome. I use the following command:

```
pkexec --user <user> google-chrome-stable --force-renderer-accessibility --app "http://my/url"
```

This shows the right url, but does not show me the onscreen keyboard when I select a text field. If I remove the pkexec it does show me the onscreen keyboard. What can I do to make it also work with the pkexec?

I use Debian 9.4 and the OSK is the gnome onscreen keyboard.

I noticed that when testing with gedit iso chrome, it works fine:

```
pkexec --user <user> gedit
```

Both executables have a similar policy file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>

  <action id="org.freedesktop.policykit.pkexec.run-chrome">
    <message>Authentication is required to run Chrome</message>
    <description>Run Chrome</description>
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable</annotate>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">TRUE</annotate>
  </action>
```

It seems like the dbus calls to show the keyboard are no longer send when I use `pkexec`. If I look at the dbus-monitor the calls do come in when I run the command

```
google-chrome-stable --force-renderer-accessibility --app "http://my/url"
```

But if I add `pkexec --user <user>` to the command it no longer sends dbus messages like this:

```
method call time=1710323137.837430 sender=:1.101 -> destination=org.gnome.Caribou.Keyboard serial=2172 path=/org/gnome/Caribou/Keyboard; interface=org.gnome.Caribou.Keyboard; member=Show
```

Comment: is virtual keyboard installed? and if so, which one?

Comment: I can activate it by using `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications screen-keyboard-enabled true'

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. It appears that a environment variable had to be copied:

```
pkexec --user <user> env QT_ACCESSIBILITY=$QT_ACCESSIBILITY bash -c "google-chrome-stable --force-renderer-accessibility --app='http://my/url'"
```